# jest test describe scope variable

Tags: testing, jestjs, puppeteer

Hello i am trying to share variables in multiple jest tests
And i tried to use like this

```
describe("User can do first process", async () => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  let page = await browser.newPage();

  test("Signup Correctly", async () => {
     //...do something test
  })

  test("Second", async () => {
     //...do something test2
  })
})
```

But it is not work for me
Debugger told me that i must contain at least one test
Seem dose not offer describe scope variable.

Then what should i do for share the variables for multiple test?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i claer this problem.

Declare all to global scope and use beforeAll jest api.

```
let browser: puppeteer.Browser;
let page: puppeteer.Page;

beforeAll(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  page = await browser.newPage();
});

//Do My Test
```

It works for my case.